# What is the point of ES6 Argument Deconstruction?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have the following Javascript object named `obj`:

```
obj = {
    val1: {
        val2: "Hello World"
    }
};
```

I could deconstruct obj in a function using something like the following:

```
function someFunction({ val1: { val2: greeting } }) {
    console.log(greeting);
}
```

for comparison's sake, here's a more traditional, vanilla function:

```
function someFunction(obj) {
    console.log(obj.val1.val2); // could have stored this in a "greeting" const for clarity if desired
}
```

my question is, is this really an improvement? Sure, utilizing `greeting` in the function body is more clear, but you can easily see how such syntax could become very dense and difficult to read for more complex objects. Is deconstruction more efficient from a performance standpoint? I have trouble imagining so, since the object should be passed by reference anyway. Maybe I'm missing something here.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Comment: In the end of the day - it's all just reading and writing from CPU registers. Everyone chooses the level of abstraction they like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using object deconstruction allows for the code to simplified in some minor ways. None of this is major life-changing stuff, but I think once people aclimitize to it, they will find it useful.

1. It makes it more explicit what arguments a function takes. Often with functions that took an `obj`, you're forced to read the function body to find what keys are valid, or check the docs.

   ```
   var foo = function(args) {
      // hmmm what keys go on args?
   }

   var foo = function({ url : url, overwrite : overwrite = false }) {
      // oh, url and overwrite, and overwrite has a default
   }
   ```
2. It saves some key strokes in the function body to avoid having to reach into nested keys.

   ```
   // forced to continually reach into the args object
   var foo = function(args) {
      if (args.nested.something === true) {
         doFn(args.nested.key);
      }
   }

   // no more reaching, everything is flat
   var foo = function({ nested : { something : something, key : key } }) {
     if (something === true) {
         doFn(key);
     }
   }
   ```
3. It allows better defaulting of nested keys.

   ```
   // old style 
   var foo = function(args) {
       args = args || {};
       args.nested = args.nested || {};
       args.nested.foo = args.nested.foo || "fooValue";
       args.nested.active = args.nested.active !== undefined ? args.nested.active : true; // can't do || on boolean true or it overwrites passed false
   }

   var foo = function({
      nested : { foo : foo = "fooValue", active : active = true } = {}
   } = {}) {
       console.log(foo, active);
   }

   // foo() - "fooValue" true
   // foo({}) - "fooValue" true
   // foo({ nested : { foo : "changed" } }) - "changed" true
   // foo({ nested : { active : false} }) - "fooValue" false
   ```

Do I use it yet, not really. But I will, it will just take me a bit to get used to it, just like `=>` and template strings, both of which I now use regularly.

Comment: great explanation, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

One difference is at first approach you can

```
return {greeting}
```

to get

```
{greeting: "Hello World"}
```

while still being able to use reference to `greeting` identifier, if needed, which points to value `"Hello World"`. Where at second example you would need to use

```
return {greeting:obj.val1.val2}
```

to get same value.